# Getting IntPtr of a delegate and invoking

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

To simulate a call from c++, I'm trying the following code

```
    private delegate void CppFuncDelegate(string message);

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("+++ BEGIN TEST +++");

        Action<string> action = str => Console.WriteLine("Received:" + str);
        IntPtr delegatePtr = action.Method.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();

        CppFuncDelegate cppFuncDelegate = (CppFuncDelegate)
           Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(delegatePtr, 
                                                        typeof(CppFuncDelegate));
        cppFuncDelegate.Invoke("Hello");
    }
```

but I get

> PInvokeStackImbalance was detected.
>   A call to PInvoke function 'Test!Test.Program+CppFuncDelegate::Invoke'
>   has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke
>   signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that
>   the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match
>   the target unmanaged signature.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**NOTE**: Please don't tell me to do action.Invoke(); that's not what this exercise is about. I want to get IntPtr handle to the delegate and use GetDelegateForFunctionPointer() and then invoke the returned delegate.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if the calling convention of the PInvoke signature matches the target unmanaged signature?

Comment: @dtb `CppFuncDelegate` takes a string and returns void and I have the action delegate declared as `Action<string>`; so I think they match. Is there any other way to check the PInvoke signature?

Comment: I wan't talking about the parameters, I was talking about the calling convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use GetDelegateForFunctionPointer() to get delegate of managed function. This is from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.RUNTIME.INTEROPSERVICES.MARSHAL.GETDELEGATEFORFUNCTIONPOINTER%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV2.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true):

> You cannot pass an invalid function pointer to
>   GetDelegateForFunctionPointer. In addition, you can only use this
>   method for pure unmanaged function pointers. You cannot use this
>   method with function pointers obtained through C++ or from
>   GetFunctionPointer. You cannot use this method to create a delegate
>   from a function pointer to another managed delegate.

I'm not sure why you can't do this, but I guess it's because Microsoft's Common Language Runtime uses FastCall calling convention, but [FastCall is not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx) for PInvoke.